# HTTP Status Code suddenly changed to 202 Method Accepted

Tags: c#, rest, iis-7.5

I am using Rest web service that have 3 method (put , get , post) and im using c#.net.

When i publish in IIS 7,5, and im invoke the get method, what i got is method accepted 202.

It should be return status code 200 OK and the data what i want.

Is there anything wrong here ?

Method Accepted 202

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what your API is set to respond with.
200 would be default but perhaps if it is expecting something else it is responding with a 202.

You have made a call but something is incorrect and processing may not have completed as expected.
Without knowing the API we cannot confirm what was wrong with your request or the processing of it.